# Searching through CheckedBoxLists for checked boxes

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a simple application that would enable me to input information into some textboxes and then, after pushing a button (called `Addbtn`) combine those into one string. This string would be added to a checkboxlist called `ConcernsChk`. When one or more of these strings are completed, the user would click the appropriate checkbox and click a button (called `CompleteSortBtn`) which would transfer that string to another checkboxlist. The issue I'm having is that my checkboxlist items do not delete according to their checked status. They delete one at a time beginning from the top and moving down.

Here's the code in question:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CompleteSortBtn.Click

    Dim Disposition As String = ""

    Dim i As Integer
    If ConcernsChk.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To (ConcernsChk.Items.Count - 1)
            If ConcernsChk.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then
                Disposition = ConcernsChk.Items(i)
                DispositionChk.Items.Add(Disposition)
                ConcernsChk.Items.Remove(Disposition)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please add Concerns before marking them complete.")
    End If
```

I keep getting an error thrown that I cannot equal 3 and I have no idea what to do from here. This is thrown whether there are 2 items in the checkboxlist or 10.

Long story short, when I push the CompleteSortBtn, I want the program to do 4 things: 1. search through ConcernChk 2. Find checked boxes 3. Send the checked boxes to DispositionChk 4. Delete the checked items from ConcernChk

My apologies for the long post and thank you for whatever help you can give.

Comment: `I keep getting an error thrown that I cannot equal 3 ` There is no such error message or exception.  Please read [Ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please provide the **full** error.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating though items not checkeditems.... count will be different.

SINCE you are removing items from the list you ALSO need to do it bottom to top.

```
    For i =  (ConcernsChk.Items.Count - 1) to 0 step - 1
        If ConcernsChk.Items(i).Checked  Then
            Disposition = ConcernsChk.Items(i)
            DispositionChk.Items.Add(Disposition)
            ConcernsChk.Items.RemoveAt(I)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: So how should I adjust the code so that it cycles through the checkeditems, sends them to another checkedboxlist, and deletes the originals from the first checkedboxlist?

Comment: So I would add this code in underneath what I already have? Or would I replace my previous code with what you have here?

Comment: replace your existing for I loop

Comment: I added the code under what you already suggested and it worked like a charm. Thank you, Trevor!